# DOS Editor with intellisense

Tags: visual-studio-2010, editor, dos, visual-studio-extensions

Is there any DOS editor with intellisense.
If Visual studio addin is there that will be more useful.

Comment: Do you mean a batch file editor?

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen http://www.drbatcher.com/ there's a free trail. Normally I just use Notepad++ or Notepad2 when editing my batch files as they give syntax highlighting.

More often I write PowerShell scripts now and use PowerGui Script editor when creating those scripts.http://powergui.org/

Answer (score 0):

Try `vim` for DOS, along with an appropriate script (there's plenty to choose from).

http://www.vim.org/download.php#pc